# Return elements of the input sequence of a linq sum

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a simple list structured as the following 2 column table:

---

```
letter|number

     a|1

     a|7

     b|2

     b|5
```

---

I would like to have a Linq query that groups on the column 'letter', sums the grouped elements of column  'number', and additionally returns the summed elements in an array. Which would result in the following table:

---

```
a | 8 | {1,7}

b | 7 | {2,5}
```

---

What I have:

```
public class GroupedRow {
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string letter { get; set; }
    public int[] elements { get; set; }
}
```

And in the program:

```
List<GroupedRow> listfromquery = numberletterlist.GroupBy(x => x.letter)
    .Select(grp => new GroupedRow() {
        number = grp.Sum(x => x.number)
        letter = grp.key.letter
        // elements=
    };
```

Even though I see other ways of doing this, I would like to do this in 1 linq query (if possible), or another simple fast way.

Answer (score 5):

`grp` is the group of elements and it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Simply select `number` from it and then convert it into an array like this:

```
List<GroupedRow> listfromquery =
    numberletterlist.GroupBy(x => x.letter)
    .Select(grp => new GroupedRow()
    {
        number = grp.Sum(x => x.number),
        letter = grp.Key,
        elements = grp.Select(x => x.number).ToArray()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
elements = grp.Select(x => x.number).ToArray()
```